# Solving for variable doesn't appear to work as expected

Tags: equation-solving

I'm using Solve to find the time `t` for `t==distance/speed`, yet when I verify if `t*speed === distance`, I'm getting False...

Am I doing something wrong?

Here's my code and the output:

```
distance = Sqrt[(L + v*t)^2 + x^2];
speed = cmedium;

t11s = Solve[t == distance/speed, t];

(* choose the positive root *)
t11 = FullSimplify[t /. t11s[[2]], assum] 

t11*speed === distance
FullSimplify[t11*speed] === FullSimplify[distance]
```

outputs:

$\frac{\sqrt{c^2 \left(L^2+x^2\right)-v^2 x^2}+L v}{c^2-v^2}$

$\text{False}$

$\text{False}$

Shouldn't I be getting `True` when checking if expressions are identical... ?

Comment: The expressions are not identical. Nor are the two sides of `(x + 1)^2 === x^2 + 2 x + 1`.  Mathematically equivalent is not the same as identical.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that `===` checks whether two expressions are exactly identical. This is not the same thing as testing equality. For example:

```
FullSimplify[x^2-1 == (x-1)*(x+1)] (* True *)
FullSimplify[x^2-1 === (x-1)*(x+1)] (* False *)
```

Also note that you have only substituted in the value of `t` on one side of the equation (with `t11`). However, `t` shows up in `distance` as well, so it needs to be substituted in there or clearly the expressions are not the same: one non-trivially depends on `t`, while the other does not.

As such, the equation to check is:

```
t*speed == distance /. t->t11
```

There it's obvious that the right hand side has nested square roots, which are difficult to bring back together without making unreliable assumptions, so `FullSimplify` does not directly resolve them.

One way to check this sort of equation is to attempt to search for counterexamples:

```
FindInstance[{(t speed != distance /. (t -> t11)), 0 < v < c}, {c, v, L, x}, Reals]
(* {} *)
```

The return of an empty list without errors means that `FindInstance` does not believe that any value of `c`, `v`, `L`, and `x` satisfies the inequality. Note that I did add the assumption that `0 < v < c`.

Comment: Interesting, thanks. The final suggestion worked for me.